# Django: Send JS dict to Django View

Tags: javascript, python, django

So, I've a JS dict and I want to send this to my Django View, because I need to use it to call a function, using a python library.

I need to send: `dir_charge` to my Django View, but this is inside a JS function called `culqi()`, that is responsible for creating the `source_id` field in the dict, and the `email` field:

**js:**

This function `culqi()` captures data from the form at the end of the question.

```
<script>

   function culqi() {
      if (Culqi.token) { // ¡Objeto Token creado exitosamente!
      var dir_charge = {
              amount: 24,
              currency_code: "PEN",
              email: Culqi.token.email,
              source_id: Culqi.token.id
                    };
      } else { // ¡Hubo algún problema!
              // Mostramos JSON de objeto error en consola
              console.log(Culqi.error);
              alert(Culqi.error.user_message);
             }
      };

</script>
```

The JS is generated when user clicks on this button:

**html:**

```
<button id="buyButton">Pagar</button>
```

Thanks to this other JS:

```
<script>

            $('#buyButton').on('click', function (e) {
                // Abre el formulario con la configuración en Culqi.settings
                Culqi.open();
                e.preventDefault();
            });

</script>
```

When user clicks he button, this form appears (it's not hardcoded in HTMl, but called from an external JS library):

```
<form class="form">
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col col-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input">
                    <input name="cardNumber" autocomplete="cc-number" type="tel" maxlength="19" class="input-card"
                           data-mask="#### #### #### ####" data-previous-value="">
                </div>
                <label for="cardNumber" class="">Número de Tarjeta</label>
                <div class="brand"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col col-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input">
                    <input name="cardExp" autocomplete="cc-exp" type="tel" maxlength="5" class="input-card"
                           data-mask="##/##" data-previous-value="">
                </div>
                <label for="cardExp" class="">Mes / Año</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input">
                    <input name="cardCVV" autocomplete="cc-csc" type="tel" maxlength="3" class="input-card"
                           data-mask="###" data-previous-value="">
                </div>
                <label for="cardCVV" class="">CVV</label>
                <a>(?)</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row" style="display: none;">
        <div class="col col-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input">
                    <select name="custom-cuotas" id="" class="">
                        <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled" hidden="hidden">Pagar en Cuotas
                        </option>
                        <option value="1">Sin Cuotas</option>
                        <option value="2">2 Cuotas</option>
                        <option value="4">4 Cuotas</option>
                        <option value="6">6 Cuotas</option>
                        <option value="8">8 Cuotas</option>
                        <option value="10">10 Cuotas</option>
                        <option value="12">12 Cuotas</option>
                        <option value="3">3 Cuotas</option>
                        <option value="5">5 Cuotas</option>
                        <option value="7">7 Cuotas</option>
                        <option value="9">9 Cuotas</option>
                        <option value="24">24 Cuotas</option>
                        <option value="48">48 Cuotas</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col col-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input">
                    <input name="cardEmail" autocomplete="email" type="email" class="input input-card">
                </div>
                <label for="cardEmail" class="">Correo Electrónico</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-pay">
        <button type="submit" class="btnAction">
            <span>Pagar </span>
            <span class="payText PEN">.24</span>
            <small>PEN</small>
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**UPDATE 1:**

urls.py:

from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'cart'

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.cart_detail, name = 'cart_detail'),
    path('full_remove/<int:cart_item_id>/', views.full_remove, name = 'full_remove'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
def cart_detail(request):
    print(amount)
    print(currency_code)
    print(email)
    print(source_id)
    pass
```

Comment: While sending data through network you can send only serialized(or serializable) data. So in your case you should serialize data on frontend through `JSON.stringify(dir_charge)` and send this data with key like dir_charge and then in django backend you can get this json data, `json.loads(request.POST.get("dir_charge"))`

Comment: @Roshan, I'll try that, nevertheless, the form populated by this thrid library has no POST method, wouldm't it be a problem?

Comment: It shouldn't but I believe what you are looking for is `Ajax` request. where you can send each data by the key, Like, `{
              amount: 24,
              currency_code: 'PEN',
              email: 'email'
              source_id: 322
                    }` this whole dict can be available directly in request, where you can access like, `amount = request.GET.get('amount);  currency_code = request.GET.get('currency_code') etc.`

Comment: @Roshan yes, exactly. Would you mind posting an answer using Ajax? I don't know ajax at all.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in comment you may be interested in Ajax, hoping you are using jQuery you can use something like

```
<script>

   function culqi() {
      if (Culqi.token) { 
       $.ajax({
              url: "your_url",
              data: {
              amount: 24,
              currency_code: "PEN",
              email: Culqi.token.email,
              source_id: Culqi.token.id
           }
              }).done(function() {
               // do something with scess
               $( this ).addClass( "done" );
              });
      } else { 
              console.log(Culqi.error);
              alert(Culqi.error.user_message);
             }
      };

</script>
```

Comment: What the url should be? The one user use to access the view? in this case "/cart".  May you complement this with how to access this data en Django View?

Comment: I've tried using this: `def cart_detail(request): amount = request.GET.get('amount')
    print("Amount from AJAX:" + str(amount))` but amount is `None`

Comment: please, see my update 1. You'll find the urls and the view that only need to print the values passed to the request.